# Using pcntl library in PHP

Tags: php, fork

I've tried to use the pcntl library in order to fork a child process in php.
Here's the simple piece of code I have:

```
  $pid = pcntl_fork();
  if ($pid != -1) {
    if ($pid) {
       print "In the parent: child PID is $pid\n";
       pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
       echo "Back in parent\n";
    } 
    else {
        print "In the child\n";
        exit(19);
    }
   } 
   else {
        echo "Fork failed!\n";
   }
```

I get the result:

**In the child**

which means that the parent didn't do anything or maybe somehow the child erased what the parent did (I don't know why..)

If I comment the line: *pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);*
I get the following result:

**In the parent: child PID is 11394 Back in parent**

In this case, the child didn't do anything..
How can this happen ? I don't understand how this works..
By the way, I'm working on XAMPP.
Could anyone give me some insights ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you running this through Apache?  If so, try running it from the CLI instead - it's not recommended to run the pcntl functions inside Apache.  Also, try putting a sleep in your child process so that it hangs around a bit longer.

Comment: *(tip)* [PHP Dark Arts: Daemonizing a Process](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-daemonizing-a-process)

Comment: *(tip)* [Tux Radar Tutorial: Process Control](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/1/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When run with the [latest version of PHP](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) (5.3.5) your example works as posted. Keep in mind that this is with the [command line binary](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). If you are **running PHP as an Apache module** then you **should not be using** the pcntl functions.

The output I got was (the pid will be different for you):

> ```
> In the parent: child PID is 4759
> In the child
> Back in parent
> ```

Comment: Ok thanks ! Is there another way to fork a process with php within an apache module ?

Comment: No, but you shouldn't be forking in Apache anyway. Are you wanting to run a script outside of the HTTP request? I suggest either setting up a cron job, or looking at something like this; http://www.zend.com/en/products/platform/product-comparison/job-queues